# Sublime Text 2: Module autocompletion for Perl (Script supporting)

Tags: perl, autocomplete, sublimetext2

Maybe I miss something about `sublime text 2` but I can't find module name autocomplete for Perl in it.
I know that this task (module name autocomplete) is simple. Just take array `@INC` in Perl and search deep in directories. Ok, this part is not a problem (add them to dictionary).

So, does `sublime text 2` have a script support or something similar?

*Dream*
It will be great if `sublime text 2` can parse all modules and take their functions for autocompletion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) should work for you. I haven't used it for Perl, but the language is supported, and it does all the things you're looking for with Python, my language of choice. You can install it through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). It will take a while to get going at first, as it has to index all your modules (you can tell it where to look in the settings), but once that's done it's a real time-saver.